# Scala parallel calculation and interrupt when one method returns a result

Tags: scala

Given the several methods

```
def methodA(args:Int):Int={
    //too long calculation
    result
}

def methodB(args:Int):Int={
    //too long calculation
    result
}

def methodC(args:Int):Int={
    //too long calculation
    result
}
```

They have the same set of arguments and return a result of the same type.

It is necessary to calculate the methods in parallel and when one method returns a result I need to interrupt others.

Comment: As Scala/Akka Futures are not cancellable, you can do the way you would do in Java (or use/write a different Scala library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting question. I'm not too experienced, so there is probably a more Scala-ish way to do this, for starters with some of the cancellable future implementations. However, I traded brevity for readability.

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Callable, FutureTask}

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def longRunningTask(foo: Int => String)(arg: Int): FutureTask[String] = {
  new FutureTask[String](new Callable[String]() {
    def call(): String = {
      foo(arg)
    }
  })
}
def killTasks(tasks: Seq[FutureTask[_]]): Unit = {
  tasks.foreach(_.cancel(false))
}
val task1 = longRunningTask(methodA)(3)
val task2 = longRunningTask(methodB)(4)

val task1Future = Future {
  task1.run()
  task1.get()
}
val task2Future = Future {
  task2.run()
  task2.get()
}
val firstFuture = Future.firstCompletedOf(List(task1Future, task2Future))
firstFuture.onSuccess({
  case result => {
    println(result)
    killTasks(List(task1, task2))
  }
})
```

So, what I did here? I crated a helper method which creates a `FutureTask` (from the Java API) which executes an `Int => String` operation on some `Int` argument. I also created a helper method which kills all `FutureTask`s in a collection.

After that I created two long running tasks with two different methods and inputs (that's your part).

The next part is a bit ugly, basically I run the FutureTasks with `Future` monad and call `get` to fetch the result.

After that I basically only use the `firstCompletedOf` method from the `Future` companion to handle the first finishing task, and when that is processed kill the rest of the tasks.

I'll probably make an effort to make this code a bit better, but start with this.

You should also have a go in checking this with different ['ExecutionContext's, and parallelism levels.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Comment: I replace killTasks on tasks.foreach(_.cancel(true)) since otherwise the threads continues to run

Comment: Ok, if it suits you. It kinda depends on the algorithm itself.